# Cannot launch instance on dedicated host

Tags: amazon-web-services, dedicated

On a**ws** i launched **a1** dedicated host, but when i want to launch an instance on the host, every host is grey, but at the same time it is an obligatory field. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, a1 is just for ARM and not for X86.